# "pipenv install --system" == "pip install"

Tags: pipenv

`pipenv install --system` will install Pipfile's contents into the global `pip` environment. Then I am wondering what is the difference from `pip install` which also install packages into the global `pip` environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pipenv install --system` will install the contents of an existing Pipfile into your global pip environment.
Using the --system option, it won't allow you to specify a specific package.

`pip install` will give you an error saying you must specify at least one package to install, or you need to point to a requirements.txt file with the `-r` parameter.

So the difference is pipenv's ability (and requirement) to use an existing Pipfile vs. pip allowing installation of individual packages (or point to a requirements.txt file).